# If $\int_X f\varphi\,\mathrm{d}\mu\leq a$, then $\int_X f\,\mathrm{d}\mu\leq a$

Tags: measure-theory, proof-explanation

Suppose that $X$ is locally compact Hausdorff space. Let $f:X\to (0,\infty)$ continuous, and let $\varphi\in C_c(X)$ with $0\leq \varphi \leq 1$. Let $a>0$, and $\mu$ a Radon measure on $X$. I read in a proof, that if once proven that $\int_X f\varphi\,\mathrm{d}\mu\leq a$, then $\int_X f\,\mathrm{d}\mu\leq a$. The author said, the conclusion follows from the following lemma, which I can't see how it has been used

> **Lemma**: Let $X$ Hausdorff space, $\mu$ Radon measure on $X$, and $\mathcal{K}$ the collection of compact subsets of $X$. If $f:X\to [0,\infty]$ is a Borel measurable function, then
> $$
> \int_{X}f\,\mathrm{d}\mu=\sup_{K\in \mathcal{K}}\int_{K}f\,\mathrm{d}\mu.
> $$

**Question**: If $\int_X f\varphi\,\mathrm{d}\mu\leq a$, how to show that $\int_X f\,\mathrm{d}\mu\leq a$ by lemma above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Urysohn's lemma, for each compact set, you can construct $\phi \in C_c(X)$ s.t. $0 \leq \phi \leq 1$ and $\phi|_K = 1$, then $\int_K f \ d\mu \leq  \int f \phi \ d\mu$. Then if you prove that $\int f \phi \ d\mu \leq a$ for each $\phi \in C_c(X)$, then by the lemma you cite, $\int f \ d\mu= \sup_{K \in \mathcal K} \int_K f \ d\mu \leq a$.

You definitely need that inequality to hold for all $\phi \in C_c(X)$, otherwise just consider $\phi =0 $ and it holds trivially for any positive $a$.

Edit: More details on constructing the $\phi$.

First a statement of Urysohn's lemma for LCH spaces:

> If $X$ is a locally compact Hausdorff (LCH) space and if $K, F \subseteq X$ are disjoint sets s.t. $K$ is compact and $F$ is closed, then there is a continuous function $\phi :X \to [0,1]$ s.t. $\phi|_K = 1$ and $\phi|_F = 0$.

Now our goal is that given any compact set $K$, we want to construct a $\phi \in C_c(X)$ s.t. $\phi|_K = 1$. Well we definitely want to use Urysohn's lemma, but what is our set $F$? Note it can't be $X^C = \emptyset$ as then we can't prove that the support is compact.

The following claim should suffice:

> Let $X$ a LCH space. Let $K \subseteq X$ compact. Then there exists an open set $U$ s.t. $K \subseteq U$ and $\overline{U}$ is compact.

Prove this claim and use it to finish the proof.

Comment: In Ursysohn's lemma, it talks about a compact set $K$ and an open set $U$, satisfying that $K\subseteq U$, then there exists $f\in C_c(X)$ such that $0\leq f\leq 1$, $f|_K\equiv 1$ and $\textrm{supp} f\subseteq U$. What should $U$ be in this problem? $X$?

Comment: @James2020: You may have to use the fact that if $f$ is a nonnegative lower semicontinuous function on $X$, then $f=\sup\{\phi\in\mathcal{C}_{00}(X): 0\leq \phi\leq f\}$ along with the fact that ever open set $G$, or rather $\mathbb{1}_G$, is lower semicontinuous.

Comment: @OliverDiaz I am not familiar with this one ... Wouldn't it possible to use only two lemmas: Urysohn's lemma and the lemma I stated in the post?

Comment: @James2020 I can add more detail. Though, you should try to figure it out yourself. I'll add some hints to my post, ask if you can't figure it out.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could add more details. I've been trying to figure it myself, since I have a different version in my book that says: "For given sets $K\subseteq U$ in a locally compact Hausdorff space $X$, where K is compact, and $U$ is open, there is $f\in C_c(X)$ such that $0\leq f\leq 1$, $f\equiv 1$ on $K$ and $\textrm{supp}f \subseteq U$." I understand using this lemma, but the problem is, what $U$ should be. If $U=X$, because $X$ itself is open, then $\textrm{supp}f\subseteq X$ means that $f\equiv 0$ on $X\setminus U=\emptyset$, which doesn't make sense. Hence the question ...

Comment: @James2020 Have you looked at my edit? If you can prove the claim I give at the end, the open set it gives should suffice.

Comment: I've just read it. I know the claim, as it has been used in a proof to prove what I just stated (book's version of Urysohn's lemma ...). What confuses me is just simply what $U$, being open set (in book's version), should be when proving the claim in the post ... I mean, how to use unknown $U$ to prove the claim in the post?

Comment: @James2020: Yes, in your version of Urysohn's lemma, you can take $U$ to be any open set that contains $K$.  $U=X$ would work.  The purpose of $U$ in the lemma is in case you want to ensure that the support of $\phi$ is not too big, but here that doesn't matter.

Comment: @James2020: Also, saying $f \equiv 0$ on $\emptyset$ does make sense.  It says that for every $x \in \emptyset$ we have $f(x) = 0$.  Since there are no $x \in \emptyset$, the statement is vacuously true for every function $f$.

Comment: @NateEldredge OK. I literally thought it wouldn't make sense for $U=X$ in the beginning. I want to know how you see it as vacuously true. If I am not mistaken, the implication $p\implies q$ is true, whenever $p$ is false, regardless the truth of $q$. Is $p="x\in \emptyset"$ and $q="f(x)=0"$?

Comment: @NateEldredge, you can't take $U = X$, since we need our $\phi$ to be compactly supported. We take $U$ to be a relatively compact neighborhood of $K$, which we can easily show exists.

Comment: @KeeferRowan: James's version of Urysohn's lemma includes the conclusion that $\phi \in C_c(X)$, so the support of $\phi$ is automatically compact.  The lemma says only that the support of $\phi$ is contained in $U$; there is nothing stopping it from being much smaller.

Comment: @NateEldredge, Yep, didn't see that at first.

Comment: @James2020: Yes, that's right.  A statement of the form "for all $x \in A$, $Q(x)$" is short for "for all $x$, $x \in A \implies Q(x)$" and with $A = \emptyset$ the antecedent $x \in \emptyset$ is always false, so the implication is always true.

Comment: @NateEldredge OK. Thanks for joining in order to help, really ...

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Let $\mathcal{K}$ denote the collection of all compact sets in $X$.

- Using Urysohn's lemma one can show that $\int_K f\,d\mu\leq a$ for all compact.
- On the other hand, $\nu(g)=\int g\,f\,d\mu$ defines a Radon measure (regular Borel measure) on $X$. By inner regularity $\mu(A)=\sup\{\nu(K): K\in\mathcal{K},\,K\subset A\}$ for all measurable sets $A$. (This is the Riesz-Markov representation theorem)

Comment: If I may ask, why do you say ".. compact sets in $X$" (and not "... compact subsets of $X$")? Is this a short-hand for saying that these sets are subsets of $X$, and that they are compact in X? Or ... ?

Comment: yes, but also to emphasize the topology on $X$.

Comment: OK, glad to know it. You wrote in your first point about Urysohn's Lemma. The version I have in the book is: "For given sets $K\subseteq U$ in a locally compact Hausdorff space $X$, where $K$ is compact, and $U$ is open, there is $f\in C_c(X)$ such that $0\leq f\leq 1$, $f\equiv 1$ on $K$ and $\textrm{supp} f\subseteq U$." The question is, what is $U$ is this situation, when trying to prove the claim I wrote in the post? Should $U$ be $X$?

Answer (score 0):

I want to point out that the lemma in the post is wrong.

Consider the following exercise from Folland's book "Real analysis: Modern techniques and their applications":

[image]

It shows that $$\int_X\chi_E d \mu= \mu(E)= \infty$$
yet
$$\sup_{K} \int_K \chi_E d \mu = \sup_K \mu(E \cap K) = 0$$
since for every compact subset $K$, $E\cap K$ is a compact subset of $E$, since $E$ is closed in $X$.